# missing property '@type' that is to contain type id when using abstract class

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jackson2

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE and handling two DTOs which have lots of fields in common so I created an abstract DTO.

I hoped that Jackson would always select the appropriate concrete DTO for the HTTP-POST.

I created this Abstract DTO like this :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = InViewModel.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = In2ViewModel.class) })
public abstract class AbstractInAndIn2ViewModel {..}
```

The concrete DTOs look like this :

```
public class InViewModel extends AbstractInAndIn2ViewModel {..}
```

and

```
public class In2ViewModel extends AbstractInAndIn2ViewModel {..}
```

My converter class which handles the DTO to DAO conversion looks like this :

```
public void convertDTO_To_DAO(AbstractInAndIn2ViewModel abstInView) {

        if (abstInView instanceof InViewModel) {

        InViewModel inView=(InViewModel)abstInView;
        In in = new In();
        in.setName(inView.getName());
        ...
        }
        if (abstInView instanceof In2ViewModel) {

        In2ViewModel in2View=(In2ViewModel)abstInView;
        In2 in2 = new In2();
        in2.setName(in2View.getName());
        ...
        }
```

The HTTP-POST call looks like this :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/item/input")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createInput(@RequestBody @Valid AbstractInAndIn2ViewModel input) {..}
```

Unfortunately, I am always getting the error message :

> Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property
>   '@type' that is to contain type id

Comment: you need to have additional field `@type` in your json so Jackson can understand how to resolve `JsonTypeInfo` This is basically how JsonTypeInfo works by default. If you don't have some field in json to distinguish between classes, then you need to wright custom deserializer

Comment: ok, thanks ! Got it working

Comment: @ThomasW Please mention how, so others may use your solution as well